# Why does moment not recognize the .add method?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
moment=require('moment'); 
const now= moment();     
const dateFormat1 = 'MMDDYYYY';
this.todaysdate = () => (`${now.format(dateFormat1)}`);
this.futuredate= () => (`${now.format(dateFormat1).add('days', 5)}`);
```

When I run this, I get that add is not a recognizable function. numerical Begindate works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `string`, which is returned from `format`, doesn't have `add` on it's prototype. Try to add on the moment instead

```
now.add('days', 5).format(dateFormat1)
```

Comment: This is close, but I get undefined when I console.log it.

Comment: console.log what? @Nighthawk

Comment: console.log(futureDate)

Comment: Ah. Please clarify in your question if you mean `this.futureDate` or `var futureDate`. Anyways, just log the correct one and call the function you created for that

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I use the function to put it into a var later on. A var works fine when todaysdate gets called. however when futureDate gets called, the var is logged as undefined.

Comment: I still don't get what you mean. However, you have assigned this.futureDate, so you need to log this.futureDate

Comment: Okay, I use 2 variables in another file and assign it using the two date functions. so I store the value from function today's date to var a. and I store the value from function futuredateto var b. when I log a, it returns the appropriate answer. When I log b, it returns undefined.

Comment: dont give up baao, we're so close!

Comment: No, you constantly refuse to give a clear problem statement. I'm not here for guessing, and the code I posted works. Just assign it properly

Comment: It is assigned properly. It returns undefined.

Comment: You were right @baao. I called it incorrectly in my other function. Thanks for your help.